# How to escape chinese in PowerShell with ConvertTo-Json?

Tags: json, powershell

I am trying to use ConvertTo-Json in PowerShell. By default, ConvertTo-Json will escape special characters. However, it will not escape chinese.

For example:

```
"<>中文ABC" | ConvertTo-Json
```

The output is

```
"\u003c\u003e中文ABC"
```

But, what I really want is "\u003c\u003e\u4e2d\u6587ABC". Can anyone share the experience?

Answer (score 0):

Found a way:

```
function ConvertTo-Rtf
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [string[]] $String
    )

    process
    {
        if ($null -eq $String) { $String = @() }
        
        $stringBuilder = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder
        foreach ($s in $String)
        {
            $stringBuilder.Length = 0
            foreach ($character in $s.GetEnumerator())
            {
                if ([int]$character -lt 0x7F)
                {
                    $null = $stringBuilder.Append($character)
                }
                else
                {
                    $null = $stringBuilder.AppendFormat('\u{0:x}', [int]$character)
                }
            }

            $stringBuilder.ToString()
        }
    }
}
```

Then `@{name="ABC<中文>" } | ConvertTo-Json -Compress| ConvertTo-Rtf`

Output:

```
{"name":"ABC\u003c\u4e2d\u6587\u003e"}
```